# do a reverse name lookup to compare the IP to localhost

Tags: command-line, hostname

i want make server ip mapping to localhost?
should i vim /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost

```
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
10.51.101.35 iZ25kpavw8zZ
localhost 123.442.23
```

i want to do a reverse name lookup to compare the IP (123.442.23) and the hostname (localhost) to determine if they are the same machine.

how to do it?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Do you want to set localhost to your public IP, or are you just looking for a way to find your public IP? I assume you are on EC2, and just see a private IP of your interface, not the public one?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want to find your public IP, and you are on EC2 machine that does not directly let you access this information. A solution is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525702/how-to-find-the-ip-address-of-an-amazon-ec2-instance-on-reboot). Execute this on the machine

```
wget -qO- http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
```

it will give you your public IP.